# Trying to find a way to use a variable / argument in an if condition inside xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this code in my xsl file

```
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; @variable">
```

but it does not work. Instead of a variable if I use a number like 10 for example, it works. My question is, how to use a variable / param / argument passed from a C# class, inside an if condition in xsl. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is my code: <xsl:if test="position() &lt; @parameter">

Comment: You need to use the `$` prefix for a variable. A `@` symbol represents an attribute in the XML.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*a variable / param / argument passed from a C# class*". If you have a *parameter* named `variable`, you would refer to it as `$variable` not `@variable`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried with $ too. Did not work. I am passing an argument from a c# class to the xsl and I can also see its value when I run the xsl code. But if I try to use that argument inside an if condition in the xsl, I just cant seem to get it to work. This one works <xsl:if test="position() &lt;=25"> but not <xsl:if test="position() &lt;=$argument">. Have been struggling with this for quite sometime now.

Comment: Is there any way to use an attribute inside the if condition?

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example - see: [mcve]

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but we can't tell what from this fragment. You haven't even told us how it fails. NEVER write on SO that something "doesn't work" - always tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write a program such that the user could select how many rows of a table he or she wanted to show in the web-browser object, and I was having some issues passing this variable value. This is how I solved it.
("attribute" is the value the user will pass from a combo-box in the UI and it could be either, 10, 25, 50, 75 or 100 rows)

First, I declared a variable and assigned it the value of the attribute.

```
<xsl:variable name="variable">
<xsl:value-of select="//@attribute"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then I used the variable in the if condtion, in this way

```
<xsl:if test="$variable &gt; position()">
```

Followed by the rest of the code to display the table.
Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You should define your variable as `<xsl:variable name="variable" select="//@attribute"/>`. It's shorter and it has other advantages which I will not go into here.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again.